Preventing overflow when multiplying by fractions
i tried to multiply integer with (17/64) rounded down, but i cannot handle overflow. (i am limited to only bitwise operators ( ~ & | << >> ! + )
#include <stdio.h>

int mulfrac(int x) {
    int mul17 = (x<<4) + x;
    int bias = (mul17 >> 31) & 63;
    int result = (mul17 + bias) >> 6;
    return result;

}

int main() {
    int test_values[] = {0, 1, -1, 3, -3, 17, -17, 11, -11, 64, -64, 128, -128, 100, -100, 400, 15, -6, 1234523590, -10000000, -10};
    int n_tests = sizeof(test_values) / sizeof(test_values[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_tests; i++) {
        int x = test_values[i];
        int result = mulfrac(x);
        printf("mul_17_div_64(%d) = %d\n", x, result);
    }

    return 0;
}

I dont know how to do since I have tried different stuff but to no avail. I can not use if and while either

Left-shifting negative values invokes undefined behavior.

@Henry "rounded down" -- For this task, does that means down toward 0 or down toward -infinity.  Result is different when the value is negative.

@Henry mul17 >> 31 assumes that int is 32 bits.  Given the various restrictions, is that also allowed?

A common issue problem  with "...  limited to only bitwise operators ( ~ & | << >> ! + )" is that coders often do not make a clear reference function for testing.  Of course the reference function does not need to follow such limitations - it can be thrown away after we get a function that behaves the same with the limitations.
Below is a test harness capturing the state of things so far.
I hope the coded mulfrac_ref() meets OP's functional goals.
Useful for testing any candidate answer.
#include <stdio.h>

int mulfrac_ref(int x) {
  int y = (int) ((x * 17LL) / 64);
  // If "round down" means to round toward -infinity and not round down to 0,
  // Then add this if().
#if 0
  if (x < 0) {
    if ((x * 17LL) % 64) {
      y--;
    }
  }
#endif
  return y;
}

int mulfrac(int x) {
  int mul17 = (x << 4) + x;
  int bias = (mul17 >> 31) & 63;
  int result = (mul17 + bias) >> 6;
  return result;
}

int mulfrac_MB(int x) {
  int bias = (x >> 31) & 1;
  int result = (x + bias) >> 2;  // x/4
  return result + (result >> 4); // (1+1/16)x/4
}

// Using a wider type may be a cheat for OP
// but leaving here as a simple alternative.
int mulfrac_chux(int x) {
  long long mul17 = ((long long)x << 4) + x;  // Left shifting negs is UB.
  int bias = (mul17 >> 31) & 63;  // Right shifting negs is implementation defined.
  int result = (int) ((mul17 + bias) >> 6);
  return result;
}

#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  int test_values[] = {0, 1, -1, 3, -3, 17, -17, 11, -11, 64, -64, 128, -128,
      100, -100, 400, 15, -6, 1234523590, -10000000, -10, INT_MAX, INT_MIN};
  int n_tests = sizeof(test_values) / sizeof(test_values[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i < n_tests; i++) {
    int x = test_values[i];
    int result = mulfrac(x);
    printf("mul_17_div_64(%12d) = %12d,%12d,%12d,%12d\n", x, mulfrac_ref(x),
        mulfrac_chux(x), mulfrac_MB(x), result);
  }

  return 0;
}

Output
mul_17_div_64(           0) =            0,           0,           0,           0
mul_17_div_64(           1) =            0,           0,           0,           0
mul_17_div_64(          -1) =            0,           0,           0,           0
mul_17_div_64(           3) =            0,           0,           0,           0
mul_17_div_64(          -3) =            0,           0,          -2,           0
mul_17_div_64(          17) =            4,           4,           4,           4
mul_17_div_64(         -17) =           -4,          -4,          -5,          -4
mul_17_div_64(          11) =            2,           2,           2,           2
mul_17_div_64(         -11) =           -2,          -2,          -4,          -2
mul_17_div_64(          64) =           17,          17,          17,          17
mul_17_div_64(         -64) =          -17,         -17,         -17,         -17
mul_17_div_64(         128) =           34,          34,          34,          34
mul_17_div_64(        -128) =          -34,         -34,         -34,         -34
mul_17_div_64(         100) =           26,          26,          26,          26
mul_17_div_64(        -100) =          -26,         -26,         -27,         -26
mul_17_div_64(         400) =          106,         106,         106,         106
mul_17_div_64(          15) =            3,           3,           3,           3
mul_17_div_64(          -6) =           -1,          -1,          -3,          -1
mul_17_div_64(  1234523590) =    327920328,   327920328,   327920328,    -7623991
mul_17_div_64(   -10000000) =     -2656250,    -2656250,    -2656250,    -2656250
mul_17_div_64(         -10) =           -2,          -2,          -4,          -2
mul_17_div_64(  2147483647) =    570425343,   570425343,   570425342,    33554431
mul_17_div_64( -2147483648) =   -570425344,  -570425344,  -570425344,   -33554432


Oops! I let a special case fence post error get away from me - well spotted. Adding the extra test cases -15, +6, +10 and -2147483647 will make things clearer for others who find this post in the future. It is all too easy to miss a few special cases.

A nice way to do it is to think about the representation of the fraction 17/64 and only use addition and right shift operations that are well behaved avoiding the multiply entirely.
  17/64 = (16 + 1)/64 = 1/4 + 1/64 = (1 + 1/16)/4

So that your code becomes:
int mulfrac(int x) {

   int bias = (x >> 31) & 1;
   int result = (x + bias) >> 2;  // x/4
   return result + (result >> 4); // (1+1/16)x/4 
}

Using only here division avoids problems with overflow. The routine name is now a bit misleading...

To prevent overflow and the undefined behavior of shifting left negative values can get both handled by breaking the computation into 2 parts: the all but 6 most significant bits and the least 6.
The most significant bits, being a multiple of 64 can form their contribution exactly by first shifting right 6 (/ 64) thus giving us the additional range needed to not overflow.  Then the lower 6 bits are handle like OP's original code.  The results of the 2 portions are then added.
Code tested with test harness with no errors.
// Only use // ~ & | << >> ! + operators.
//
// To avoid overflow, break the `int` value into 2 parts:
// All but the least 6 bits and the least 6 bits.
// Scale each by 17/64.  The first part suffers no rounding and no overflow.
// The least 6 bits perform like OP's original code.
int mulfrac_chux(int x) {
  // First handle multiple of 64
  int one64th = x >> 6;  // This is a divide by 64 with round toward -infinity.
  // OP apparently want round toward 0.

  // To avoid UB of ((x << 4) + x) with negative numbers,
  int result1 = one64th;
  int result2 = result1 + result1;
  int result4 = result2 + result2;
  int result8 = result4 + result4;
  int result16 = result8 + result8;
  int result17 = result16 + result1;

  // Now handle the sign and last 6 bits.
  int bias = (x >> 31) & 63;  // sign bit: implementation defined behavior.  Assumes a s 32-bit int.
  x &= 63;
  int mul17 = (x << 4) + x;  // Scale x, (x is >= 0) by 17, so we can use <<
  int result = (mul17 + bias) >> 6;

  return result + result17;
}


Add bias before dividing. To avoid ovderflow issues with negative numbers you need to round the result correctly. This can done b adding a "bias" for negative numbers before dividing by 64.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
